# Where can I set the default filter for webforms?

Tags: webforms

When I go to
https://example.com/admin/structure/webform

I would like to have the webform filtered by active ones.

Where do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no UI setting for that.

You have to change it programmatically via custom module in `mymodule.module` file or via theme in `mytheme.theme` file.

Example:

**mytheme.theme**

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function mytheme_form_webform_filter_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['filter']['state']['#default_value'] = 'open';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to override and extend the \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionListBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Since the webform 8.x-5.9

you can change (your filteroptions) under

/admin/structure/webform/config

FORM OVERVIEW SETTINGS
Filter webforms default category?

Select the filter webforms default category selected on the webform overview page.
Filter webforms default state?

Thanks Jake.